# Which is the biggest character shown so far in One Piece?

Tags: one-piece

From what I can tell the candidates for largest character in One Piece are:

1) Laboon, enormous whale of questionable scale at the entrance to the grand line.

2) Surume, the enormous kraken tamed by Luffy was shown to wear the Thousand Sunny on its head like a small hat.

3) Sanjuan Wolf, from pictures posted in the Manga he has been shown to be the size of Navy Headquarters

4) Seakings, some of the seakings shown in the calm belt seamed enormous, and perhaps they aren't even the largest.

5) Island Eater, the island eating goldfish was shown to be several times larger than the giants on Little Garden. Though I'm not sure it's size matches up.

I think Sanjuan Wolf is the largest, but I'm honestly not sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Zou, the living elephant on which the animals of Mink reside is the largest character so far shown. The entire back of the elephant has so much space that there are forests, rivers and even entire towns on it. There's an entire country there.[image]

[image]

Comment: Still think the Florian Triangle Monster >> Living Island Zou. Since Thriller bark ~= Island in itself and the monster bigger then him.

Comment: Also, I'll recommend removing the images having mangafox and mangapanda on them.

Answer (score 5):

Couldn't find the sources but lets take a look at some of my top candidates.

> Wolf is a giant of extraordinary size, towering over even the largest beings known to date like Oars or Little Oars Jr., as well as being so big that he appears to be roughly the same size as the Marine Headquarters at Marineford, and is thus the biggest known giant to date, living up to his well-deserved nickname.

Wolf maybe huge but still a giant. But I am guessing his size is that of a Marine batttleship.

Coming to Island Eater GoldFish and Island Whales(Laboon). Both were able to swallow the Going Merry with ease, though Laboon seemed larger. However I can still see them being larger than San Juan Wolf. Seakings were almost the size of Noah the ship, so they are bigger.

But this is clearly the biggest thing shown (but not explained) in One Piece. In anime, this was shown as something with red eyes
This thing clearly eclipses the Thriller Barque ship, which we know San Juan Wolf is smaller than :P[image: Unknown Monster OP]

Comment: I'd like to mention that at the battle of Marineford we saw that even Oars Jr was about the size of two battleships stacked on top of each other. And if Sanjuan Wolf is about four times the size of him, then we're talking about someone about half the size of Thriller Bark.

Comment: @Ethan722 Good point. But thrller barque was way bigger.. Since Little Oars was "little" and Oars at max was half the size of Wolf. No way Sanjuan wolf half the size of Thriller barque. Thriller barque imho has the same island area as that of Living Island Zou.

Answer (score 2):

If you seen the [one piece: heart of gold](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Heart_of_Gold), then there [Bonbori sama](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Bonbori) which is a football fish. Inside its body, Bonbori has three stomachs which hold several islands, including the island of Alchemi in its third. 
[image]

Comment: Is heart of gold canon?

Answer (score 0):

The biggest thing is definitely the huge shadow at the start of the Jaya arc. I mean its at least 100.000 times bigger than  The Going merry